# Who manages a JMS session on the consumer side

Tags: jms, jms-session

If I have a JMS queue and I wish to put a message on the queue from a publishing client, I need to first open a session, get the queue from its jndi name and then send the message to the queue.

But on the consumer side, how come I do not manually need to open a session and receive the message. Does the container always keep one open session per MDB (considering one MDB listening on one queue)

Comment: The consumer is MDB, not standalone JMS client?

Comment: Ummyes..but on your point, is it possible to have a standalone client as consumer? I have always seen only MDBs.

Comment: Of course, standalone clients are very common, but you need to manage the connection and session manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using MDB's, which are container-managed objects, the connection, session, queue/topic, and actual consumer are all managed by the container.

You just write the code for `onMessage(Message m)`, that's it.

Comment: So each time a message comes on the queue the container will open a session between the MDB and the queue?

Comment: that depends on how the container handles it. It may keep the session open for resue, or it may not and create a new one for each messages. Check the documentation for the app server you're using.